# Tan function in java

Tags: java

I write a program like this:

```
double degrees = 45.0;
double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
System.out.println(Math.tan(radians));
```

When I run this code I get the result is 0.9999999999999 
Is there a way to calculate the correct tan function in java? Can you help me. Thank you!

Comment: Using doubles will always create rounding issues. If you don't care too much about precision you can simply round the result to n decimals.

Comment: why don't you round it?